# What is a node in a Power Grid

Tags: power-grid

I have heard the term Node in the Power Grid or Smart Grid, what does this node compose of? Is it a group of houses connected to the same substation?

Comment: The literal meaning of "node" is "knot" so, where wires are tied together. Or, junctions.

Answer (score 2):

"Node" (or: vertex) really is just a term from graph theory and describes any point in a graph where two edges connect.

Whether that is a single device, power outlet, house, a substation, a nuclear power plant or a national exchange where GWh are auctioned depends on the context. You'll need to really look into the details of each publication – "power grid" or "smart grid" doesn't define that.

Answer (score 0):

A node is essentially a junction box provided to different regions of the state. It allows for more expansion from power grids to various houses in the region. A simple definition of a node is where two or more wires meet.

Some Nodes have smart systems that makes sure there is regulation in supplying mains voltage. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

A node in power transmission can be a *power plant*, *substation*, *tap*, or *Junction*. Taps & junctions are essentially where the power line splits in many directions and usually done on the power pole.